# How do I fill in an input using javascript on an angular site?

Tags: angular, web, authentication, passwords

I'm trying to run a script on a website that fills in the username and password and then clicks the login button. However after I do that i get an error message telling me that I need to enter a username and password. The site is an angular site and I suspect that angular doesn't notice that the input fields have been interacted with. Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Comment: You have to simulate keyboard events for this to work. If you don't, Angular doesn't consider that you are modifying the value of the input. You can also try to use `ng.probe(yourRefToTheInput).componentInstance` into the console and see if it can access the Angular component. From there, you can probably fetch the form group and fill it with `setValue`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but since I haven't written the website myself, I don't seem to be able to access angular through the console. when i write ng for example, i get Uncaught ReferenceError: ng is not defined. I have tried writing 'angular.' but no luck there either. I have also tried to simulate the keys like this:
input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'T'}));
input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'T'}));
input.value += 'T';
input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup',{'key':'T'}));

But that hasn't worked either. Any suggestions?